# differentiating between a function pointer and member function pointer

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, word-wrap, pointer-to-member

I this code, which appears to work:

```
template <typename C>
class class_ {
protected:
    std::map<std::string, native_function> methods;
public:
    template <typename F, F fn>
    class_ &method(const std::string &name) {
        methods[name] = method_helper<C, F>::template toNative<fn>();
        return *this;
    }
};
```

which allows for:

```
class_<MyClass>()
    .method<decltype(&MyClass::numRows), &MyClass::numRows>("numRows");
```

However, I would also like to allow for non-member functions to be added as methods to my exported class. The issue is I need a different definition of `method` to work with the normal function pointers:

```
template <F, F fn>
class_ &method(const std::string &name) {
    methods[name] = function_helper<F>::template toNative<fn>();
    return *this;
}
```

However, as shown above, the template parameters would be exactly the same.

Besides creating an function with an entirely different name, is there convenient way to differentiate between function pointers and member-function pointers? Or is there a way at runtime to determine which code to run?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you are trying to make some kind of script binding system. Do you know about [cpgf](http://cpgf.org)? It is very much like luabind (which I suppose you know), but supports python, lua and javascript.

Comment: I am -- CPGF looks interesting, thanks for the link. I started working on this code in part because I wanted to better understand the c++11 standard, but also because I wanted a lightweight wrapper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With [SFINAE](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/06/01/almost-static-if.html):

```
template<
    typename F
    , F fn
    , typename std::enable_if<
        std::is_member_pointer<F>::value
        , int
    >::type...
>
class_ &method(const std::string &name)
{
    methods[name] = method_helper<C, F>::template toNative<fn>();
    return *this;
}

template<
    typename F
    , F fn
    , typename std::enable_if<
        !std::is_member_pointer<F>::value
        , int
    >::type...
>
class_ &method(const std::string &name)
{
    methods[name] = function_helper<F>::template toNative<fn>();
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: I was hoping for solution like this! Unfortunately, it appears to not work with the current version of clang++. Just to double check, I tried compiling the same code with g++ 4.6, and it compiled without a problem. The error I get with clang++ is when I try to call `method`, it complains that `method` is ambiguous.

Comment: @AbeSchneider Could be an artifact of the [SFINAE technique](http://rmartinho.github.com/2012/06/01/almost-static-if.html). Try `= 0` instead of the `...` ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

A non-member function pointer in your example would have the signature:

```
template<typename Ret, typename Args...> Ret (*)(Args args...)
```

and a member function pointer the signature:

```
template<typename Ret, typename Args...> Ret (C::*)(Args args...)
```

This allows you to specialize on the two signatures:

```
template <typename F, F fn>
class_ &method(const std::string &name) { return method_impl(name, fn); }

template <typename F>
class_ &method_impl(const std::string &name, F fn)
{
    // non-member function variant.
}

template <typename Ret, typename Args...>
class_ &method_impl(const std::string &name, Ret (C::*fn)(Args args...))
{
    // member function variant.
}
```

NOTE: If you change `method_impl` to `method`, you can simplify your API, allowing:

```
class_<MyClass>().method("numRows", &MyClass::numRows);
```